# Mathematica can't solve this integral, any tips?

Tags: definite-integrals

$$0.5
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }
\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 (c+k L)^2}}
         -\frac{-2 c e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 c^2}}
                +\frac{\sqrt{\pi } x (\text{erf} x)}{2 (c+k L)}
                -\frac{\sqrt{\pi } x (\text{erf} x)}{2 c}
                +2 c e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 (c+k L)^2}}
                +2 k L e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 (c+k L)^2}}}
                {2 k L}
      }
{\frac{-2 c e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 c^2}}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi } x (\text{erf} x)}{2 (c+k L)}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } x (\text{erf} x)}{2 c}+2 c e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 (c+k L)^2}}+2 k L e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 (c+k L)^2}}}{2 k L}+e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 (c+k L)^2}}} \, dx
$$

Will settle for:

$$
0.5 \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 (c+k L)^2}}-\frac{-2 c e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 c^2}}+\sqrt{\pi } x \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2 (c+k L)}\right)-\sqrt{\pi } x \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2 c}\right)+2 c e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 (c+k L)^2}}+2 k L e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 (c+k L)^2}}}{2 k L}}{\frac{-2 c e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 c^2}}+\sqrt{\pi } x \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2 (c+k L)}\right)-\sqrt{\pi } x \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2 c}\right)+2 c e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 (c+k L)^2}}+2 k L e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 (c+k L)^2}}}{2 k L}} \, dx
$$

Comment: replacing $e^{\ldots}$ by $\exp(\ldots)$ will go a long way to make this readable

Comment: Geez , where did you find this monstrosity?